# Checkbox on my To Do list isn't working

Tags: checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm trying to create a simple to do list using only javascript and html.
Whenever a user checks the check-box I'd like the check box's css to change with a text decoration of a line-through.
While debugging I figured the function DeleteToDo isn't even invoked by the event of change.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```js
var todo = "";

$(document).ready(function (){

    $("button").on("click", addATodo);
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", deleteTodo());


});

function addATodo(){
    var todo = $("input").val();
    console.log(todo);
    $("div").append('<input type="checkbox"><p>' + todo + '</p><br/>');
}

function deleteTodo(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("p").css("text-decoration","line-through");

    }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="To do"/>
<button>Add a To Do</button>
<br>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included `jQuery` in your code. Put the HTML `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your code.

As well, when the button is pressed, your program doesn't even know that the button was pressed, and does nothing in response. What you need to do is add an `on-click listener` to the button, like so:

`<button`**`onclick=addATodo()`**`>Add a To Do</button>`

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", deleteTodo());
```

You need to pass the function. So make it `deleteTodo` (without the `()`). Also, this will only create that call back for `input[type='checkbox']`s that  are already in the DOM. You have to re-add the `.on()` after every checkbox you make. This would do the trick:

```
function addATodo(){
    var todo = $("input").val();
    var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox"><p>'+todo+'</p></input><br />')
    $("div").append(checkbox);
    checkbox.on("click", deleteTodo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked just great, but that leads me to another question, if possible: can't I manipulate new added elements after the DOM was loaded?

Comment: Sure, you can ask it here in the comments, I can edit my answer.

Comment: just edited my comment (accidentally pressed enter:))

Comment: You can add/manipulate them, but the `on-change` (or similar) callbacks will not be automatically added when you create a new element... I would discourage calling `$("input[type='checkbox']").on(...)` over and over again, because you will actually have an element with like 5 on-change callbacks because you are adding it over and over again. That is why I created a `checkbox` variable, and assigned the on-change **only** to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from forgetting to add jQuery, the most important mistake is here:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", deleteTodo());
```

Since there's no checkboxes yet when the document is loaded, jQuery will not attach any listeners. In addition you must pass the function `deleteTodo` itself, not the return value. So remove the `()`.

I've changed it into this. You might want to read the entire snippet to understand what is going on.

```
$("#todos").on("change input[checkbox]", deleteTodo);
```

This will attach the listener to a parent element with the id `#todos`. In general it's better to use ids and classes as selectors in jQuery, since using tags such as `div` often will target a lot of elements that you didn't want to manipulate.

I also changed the deleteTodo function to use toggleClass instead of modifying the css inline. To only modify the text of a single todo, you must get that value from the event that is passed to deleteTodo. Your code would have modified every `p` element in the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", addATodo);
  $("#todos").on("change input[checkbox]", deleteTodo);
});

function addATodo() {
  var todo = $("input").val();
  $("#todos").append(
    '<div class="todo"><input type="checkbox"/>' + todo + '</div>');
}

function deleteTodo(event) {
  $(event.target).parent().toggleClass("strikethru");
}
```

```css
.strikethru {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="To do" />
<button id="button">Add a To Do</button>
<div id="todos"></div>
```